# How to get values from specific column in MySQL table, then display it on new page

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a simple question and I'm stuck with it. I have to use the same logic like in the provided code, but this time I have to make a new page - let's say `"article.php"`, then I have to change the `"Delete"` button with `"Show"` button.

This is easy, but I can't do the following thing:

When a user clicks on the "SHOW" button, the link must redirect him into the "article.php" page, and after that to display ALL of the VALUES for the selected COLUMN.
How is this going to happen? Using `"foreach"` cycle again or?... 
I really don't know how to do it.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
<?php

include "app".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config.php";
include "app".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."db-connection.php";

$foo_connection = db_connect($host, $user_name, $user_password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$result = mysqli_query($foo_connection, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    print "<table>
              <tr>
                <th>Article ID</th>
                <th>Article heading</th>
                <th>Article text</th>
                <th>Article author</th>
                <th>Article published</th>
                <th>Article delete</th>
              </tr>";
    foreach($result as $key => $cols){

        print "<tr>".
                  "<td>".$cols['id']."</td>".
                  "<td>".$cols['heading']."</td>".
                  "<td>".$cols['text']."</td>".
                  "<td>".$cols['author']."</td>".
                  "<td>".$cols['published']."</td>".
                  "<td><a href='app/sql/delete.php?id=".$cols['id']."'>Delete</a></td>".
              "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}
else {
    print "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($foo_connection);
```

Comment: use `$_GET['']` or use session

Comment: Hello, Dean.. Can you be a little bit more specific, please. :)

Comment: okay , create a the article.php then display the articles on that page by the `$_GET['id']` values on the same page , so the url would be `url/article.php?set=id` just like that  -

Comment: Ok I will try it, my friend.

Comment: It is not duplication, my friend, I have to use the same logic :).. It's different, may be a little, but it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new page, change the link from:

```
<a href='app/sql/delete.php?id=".$cols['id']."'>Delete</a>
```

To:

```
<a href='app/sql/articledetails.php?id=".$cols['id']."'>Show</a>
```

Then create a page `articledetails.php` that displays a single record based on the argument passed in `id`.

Use a SQL statement that selects just the one row:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articlesWHERE id = ?";
```

Then bind the `$_GET['id']` value to the SQL statement and execute it. Then display the row as needed.

Comment: Great, I will try it now!